# Why Laravel broadcast event always use the "laravel_database_channel" channel and how to change it?

Tags: php, laravel, redis, docker-compose, laravel-echo

I try to include Laravel-echo in project for some things.
I'm working with docker-compose containers and added 2 containers for redis and Laravel-echo-server. All containers working correctly. (php, nginx, postgres, redis, laravel-echo)

Set up .env for broadcast and redis.
Made Event for broadcast and try simple execute script with

event(new LegalizationImporterMessage("test"));

On client js (Vue) I can connect to Laravel echo.

Events always use the "laravel_database_channel"

The problem is that I don't know where I have to change smth that Events use my channel and not that "laravel_database_channel"

I've tried change the "broadcastOn" function but it not working.

.env file

```
BROADCAST_DRIVER=redis
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=redis
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=redis
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379
```

Laravel-echo-server.json

```
{
  "authHost": "nginx",
  "authEndpoint": "/broadcasting/auth",
  "clients": [],
  "database": "redis",
  "databaseConfig": {
    "redis": {
      "port": "6379",
      "host": "redis"
    }
  },
  "devMode": true,
  "host": "",
  "port": "6001",
  "protocol": "http",
  "socketio": {},
  "secureOptions": 67108864,
  "sslCertPath": "",
  "sslKeyPath": "",
  "sslCertChainPath": "",
  "sslPassphrase": "",
  "subscribers": {
    "http": true,
    "redis": true
  },
  "apiOriginAllow": {}
}
```

EventFile

```
class LegalizationImporterMessage implements ShouldBroadcast
{
    use  SerializesModels;

    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return \Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new Channel('channel');
    }
}
```

```
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
laravel-echo_1  | Channel: laravel_database_channel
laravel-echo_1  | Event: App\Events\LegalizationImporterMessage
```

Comment: What is `Laravel-echo-server`? AFAIK laravel-echo is just a Javascript package to deal with web sockets

Comment: https://github.com/tlaverdure/laravel-echo-server

Answer (score 2):

This is being set by `config('database.redis.options.prefix')` in *config/database.php*. To set a blank prefix, add this to your *.env*:

```
REDIS_PREFIX=
```

That will ensure you have no prefix as you intend and your broadcasts should now work.

Comment: I was running into similar issue,and this fixed it for me :)